# Django admin, limit select list in add item form

Tags: python, django-admin

I have 3 model classes

1. Tour
2. Tourist
3. Photos

In order to be able to add photos to a tour a user must be signed up to a tour.

what i am trying to do in the admin panel "Tour"->"add photo" form is to display only the list of tourists that are listed in the chosen tour.

what is the simplest way to do this?

My Models (most of the code there is irrelevant to the question but i guess it could help):

```
class Tourist(models.Model):

REQ_FIELDS = ["pk", "name", "email", "phone_number", "facebook_id",
              "phone_is_verified", "is_banned", "bus_id"]

name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
email = models.EmailField()
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 30,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True,
                                default="")
facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length = 255,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               default="")
phone_verification_hash = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                                           blank=True,
                                           null=True,
                                           default="")
phone_is_verified = models.BooleanField(default = False)
is_banned = models.BooleanField(default = False)
backoffice_notes = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, default="", max_length=250)
bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, blank = True, null = True, related_name="tourists")
is_admin_added = models.BooleanField(default = False)

creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone()).replace(microsecond=0))
modified_date = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone()).replace(microsecond=0), auto_now=True)

lang = models.CharField(choices =(("he", "Hebrew"), ("en", "English"),), default = "he", max_length = 100)

def need_phone_verification(self):
    return bool(self.phone_number) and not self.phone_is_verified

def is_phone_verified(self):
    """
    can he receive sms?
    """
    return bool(self.phone_number) and self.phone_is_verified

def is_facebook_verified(self):
    return bool(self.facebook_id)

def login_is_verified(self):
    """
    can he upload photos?
    """
    return not self.is_banned and \
               (self.is_phone_verified() or self.is_facebook_verified()) or \
               self.is_admin_added

def verify_phone(self):
    ans = self.send_verification_code()
    return ans

def send_verification_code( self ):
    random.seed( timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone()) )
    verify_code = str( int(random.random() * 9000 + 1000))

    if sms_verify_send( self.phone_number, verify_code ):
        self.phone_verification_hash = hashlib.sha1(verify_code).hexdigest()
        self.save()
    else:
        raise Exception("Bad SMS Server")
    return verify_code

def receive_verification_code( self, submitted_code ):
    if hashlib.sha1(submitted_code).hexdigest() == \
            self.phone_verification_hash:

        self.phone_is_verified = True
        self.save()
        return True
    return False

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s (%s, %s)" % ( self.name, self.email, self.phone_number )

def to_dict(self):
    obj = {}
    for field_name in self.REQ_FIELDS:
        obj[field_name] = getattr(self, field_name)
    return obj

def image_name(self):

    hebrew_test = any(u"\u0590" <= c <= u"\u05EA" for c in self.name)
    if hebrew_test:
        # if the name is in hebrew we flip it over so it will display 
        # correctly
        self.name= self.name[::-1]

    ans = self.name
    if self.is_phone_verified():
        if hebrew_test:
            ans = "(%s) %s" % (self.phone_number[-4:], self.name )
        else:
            ans = "%s (%s)" % (self.name, self.phone_number[-4:] )
    return ans
```

class Tour(models.Model):

```
REQ_FIELDS = ["pk", "title", "start_time", "end_time", "display_order",
              "is_cancelled" ]

title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
start_time = models.DateTimeField()
end_time = models.DateTimeField()
custom_logo = models.FileField(help_text="Please use a png file",
                               upload_to='media/tour_logo',
                               blank=True,
                               null=True,
                               validators=[is_png_ext])
display_order = models.IntegerField(choices = ((1, 'First in, First out'),
                                               (2, 'First in, Last out'),
                                               (3, 'Equal among users'),
                                               (4, 'Equal among busses')))
is_cancelled = models.BooleanField(default = False)

busses = models.ManyToManyField(Bus, blank=True, null=True, related_name = "tours")
tourists = models.ManyToManyField(Tourist, blank=True, null=True, related_name = "tours")
tourists_to_be_informed = models.ManyToManyField(Tourist, blank=True, null=True, related_name = "tours_to_be_informed")
transportation_company_provider = models.ForeignKey(Transportation_company, related_name = "tours")

backoffice_notes = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, default="", max_length=250)

client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name="tours")

is_album_sent = models.BooleanField("Was the Album sent", default = False)

tourist_validator_mail = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)

creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone()).replace(microsecond=0))
modified_date = models.DateTimeField(default=lambda: timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone()).replace(microsecond=0), auto_now=True)

def is_valid(self):
    start = self.start_time
    # now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # we us time-zone aware time
    now = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone())


    return start < now and not self.is_album_sent and not self.is_cancelled

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"%s" % self.title

def to_dict(self):
    obj = {}
    for field_name in self.REQ_FIELDS:
        obj[field_name] = getattr(self, field_name)
    return obj

def compare_date(self, curr ):
    """
    checks if time is before tour started ( then is with minus )
    or in the tour time ( with value 0 )
    or after ( with plus )
    """
    start = self.start_time
    end = self.end_time
    if curr < start:
        return -1
    if end < curr:
        return 1
    return 0

def began_and_running(self):
    # we us time-zone aware time
    time_now = timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone())
    began_and_running = self.start_time < time_now and self.photos.count() > 4
    return began_and_running

def inform(self):
    from views import contact
    if self.tourists_to_be_informed.count() > 0:
        if self.began_and_running():
            for tourist in self.tourists_to_be_informed.all():
                contact(tourist, "joined_past_notice", self)
                self.tourists_to_be_informed.remove(tourist)

def stats(self):
    return {"id": self.id,
            "title": self.title,
            "day_count": (self.end_time - self.start_time).days,
            "photo_count": self.photos.count(),
            "photo_removed_count": self.photos.filter(is_removed=True)
                                              .count(),
            "tourist_count": self.tourists.count()}

def album_link(self, tourist_id):
    query = Tour.encode_link(self.id, tourist_id)
    relative_url = build_url("pictours_app:album", get = {"query": query})

    msg = "http://%s%s" % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, relative_url)
    return msg

def slideshow_link(self, tourist_id):
    query = Tour.encode_link(self.id, tourist_id)
    relative_url = build_url('pictours_app:slideshow', get = {"query": query})

    msg = "http://%s%s" % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, relative_url)
    return msg

def transportation_company(self):
    tc = self.photos.exists() and self.photos.all()[0].bus.transportation_company
    return tc

def admin_link(self):
    relative_url = build_url('admin:pictours_app_touractive_change', args = (self.id,))

    msg = "http://%s%s" % (Site.objects.get_current().domain, relative_url)
    return msg

@staticmethod
def encode_link(tour_id, tourist_id):
    encoded = tour_id * BIG_PRIM_NUM + tourist_id
    return encoded

@staticmethod
def decode_link(query):
    int_query = query and int(query)
    pk = int_query / BIG_PRIM_NUM
    tourist_id = int_query % BIG_PRIM_NUM
    return (pk, tourist_id)

def validate_album_link(self):
    return self.album_link( -1 )
```

class Photo(models.Model):

```
REQ_FIELDS = ["pk", "s3_url"]

s3_url = models.URLField("Photo storage url", max_length=250)
s3_url_processed = models.ImageField("Processed photo",
                                     max_length=250,
                                     upload_to=Photo_upload_path,
                                     null = True)

s3_url_album = models.ImageField("Album size photo",
                                 max_length=250,
                                 upload_to=Photo_upload_path,
                                 null = True)

s3_url_thumbnail = models.ImageField("Thumbnail size photo",
                                     max_length=250,
                                     upload_to=Photo_upload_path,
                                     null = True)

tour = models.ForeignKey(Tour, related_name="photos")

tourist = models.ForeignKey(Tourist,
                            related_name="photos")

bus = models.ForeignKey(Bus, related_name="photos")

description = models.CharField("backoffice notes",
                               max_length=250,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               default="")

is_featured = models.BooleanField(default = False)
is_removed = models.BooleanField(default = False)
tourist_removed = models.ForeignKey( Tourist,
                                     related_name="removed_photos",
                                     verbose_name="Tourist who removed photo",
                                     help_text="Valid when photo is removed",
                                     null=True,
                                     blank=True)

creation_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=lambda: timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone()).replace(microsecond=0),
    editable=False)

# creation_date = models.DateTimeField(
#     default=lambda: datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')).replace(microsecond=0),
#     editable=False,
#     blank=True)



modified_date = models.DateTimeField(
    default=lambda: timezone.make_aware(datetime.datetime.now(),timezone.get_default_timezone()).replace(microsecond=0),
    auto_now=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from views import handle_photo
    self.bus = self.tourist.bus
    handle_photo(self, self.tour.client)
    self.tour.inform()
    super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.

def to_dict(self):
    obj = {}
    for field_name in self.REQ_FIELDS:
        obj[field_name] = getattr(self, field_name)
    return obj

def __unicode__(self):
    return u"<photo>tourist: %s @tour: %s" % (self.tourist, self.tour)
```

Comment: Show us your models.py please

Answer (score 0):

Django admin can handle different user permissions:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

> Permissions can be set not only per type of object, but also per
>   specific object instance. By using the has_add_permission(),
>   has_change_permission() and has_delete_permission() methods provided
>   by the ModelAdmin class, it is possible to customize permissions for
>   different object instances of the same type.